# Trent Richardson's Datetimepicker not showing Time Picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

Trent Richardson's Datetimepicker is not showing the time picker (only jQuery's date picker). Tested it 2 months ago and it is working properly. Just upgraded the JS last month.

1. This is the current js imports:

   - jquery-1.8.2.min.js
   - jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js
   - jquery.ui.slideraccess.js (version 0.2.1)
   - jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js (version 1.0.0)
2. already tried .removeClass('hasDatepicker'); since it is appending to the class after initialization of datetimepicker
3. the line $('#dateId').datetimepicker({
   is causing a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dateId' of null, have to use jQuery instead of $
4. already tried reverting to jquery-1.7 and updating Trent's scripts to a later version but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: okay it's working now. jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js was imported twice. from one of its parents.

Comment: Please delete your question if you got your answer.

Comment: I'm glad it's not deleted, I've wasted over half a day trying to get it to work and this may help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad that @Sophie asked and answered this question because I had the same problem and hadn't been able to figure it out until seeing this post.

Apparently, my site loaded `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` and then loaded another javascript file (e.g. my-site.min.js), which was a server-generated collection of smaller javascript files, all minified.

This bundle js file (e.g. my-site.min.js) contained `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` too, so jquery-ui was getting loaded twice, which apparently caused the datetimepicker to NOT show the time fields.

I simply removed the line for `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` (so that my site was now serving it up only once), and now datetimepicker works again.